How to Extend the Reach of Global Path Planning in Nav2 for Large Open Areas?
My operational environment is a vast bayland terrain, where the robot needs to navigate effectively over long distances between waypoints (In Red).

Issue Description:
My global planner struggles to generate paths to distant goals; it seems limited to approximately twice the length of my truck (about 20 meters). Given my application, I require the planner to handle much longer direct routes between sparse waypoints (ideally reducing from 30 to about 3 main waypoints). The frequent recalculations for many close waypoints lead to inefficient and unstable path planning (I've made a lot of adjustments, but having intermediate paths for each set of waypoints is getting in the way of smooth behavior and a larger, more global route)
Current Setup:
Robot Specs: Autonomous truck, approximately 10 meters in length.
Navigation System: ROS2 with the Nav2 stack.
Planner Used: SMAC planner.
Environment: Large open bayland terrain.
Attempted Solutions:
Adjusted max_planning_time and max_iterations to allow the planner more resources.
Experimented with downsampling_factor and downsample_costmap to cover larger areas with reduced computational demand.
Considered altering the resolution of the global costmap, though this might lose critical environmental details. Even considerably reducing the resolution, any improvement in generate a path to distant goal waypoints were not noticed.
The configuration file is attached: nav2_params.yaml
Questions:

Are there specific parameters or configuration changes in Nav2 or
the SMAC planner that could extend the planner's effective range
without frequent recalculations for dense waypoints?

Could adjusting the planner's behavior in large open areas help achieve smoother transitions between waypoints?


I am particularly interested in configuring the MPPI's controller parameters to more closely emulate typical driver behaviors when following GPS waypoints. Despite extensive parameter tuning, each new GPS-fed waypoint abruptly alters the truck's motion—laterally shifting or changing orientation abruptly rather than maintaining a straight path towards the waypoint. This behavior persists even with fine-tuned parameters that theoretically should facilitate smoother transitions. Given these challenges, could reducing the number of waypoints to streamline the trajectory be a practical solution? How might this impact the overall effectiveness of the path planning and vehicle control in such expansive environments?
The video below demonstrates the planner not being able to generate the Third waypoint (which is not too far from the second one). Each waypoint is distant not more than 2 and a half truck in length:
Waypoint Follower Stuck on Third Wp

I fixed the issue by just increasing my global costmap size. I thought the path planner could plan even in unknown spaces setting the track_unknow_space to true on the configuration file. However, that is not enough. The path planner works much better, faster, and more reliably INSIDE the costmap AREA. The image says for itself better than my explanation:

The global path in red
